# Is it better to use Type.GetMethod and Delegate.CreateDelegate or associate delegate with a mothod manually using switch? C#

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, delegates

I want to associate a delegate with a method at run-time, according to a text file specifying method name. Would it be faster to use something like

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class MethodCollection
{
    public static void Method1(){};
    public static void Method2(){};
}


delegate void DelegateDef();

void ExecuteMethod(string methodName)
{
    DelegateDef myDelegate;
    Type type=typeof(MethodCollection)

    MethodInfo methodInfo=type.GetMethod(methodName);
    myDelegate=Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(DelegateDef),methodInfo);
    myDelegate();
}
```

or

```
void ExecuteMethod(string methodName)
{
    DelegateDef myDelegate;
    Type type=typeof(MethodCollection)

    if (methodName=="Method1")
    {
        myDelegate+=MethodCollection.Method1;
    }
    else if (methodName=="Method2")
    {
        myDelegate+=MethodCollection.Method2;
    }

    myDelegate();
}
```

(I suppose it's irrelevant but my target will be iOS and Android.)

Comment: What *language* is this?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. It's C#.

Comment: And now that you've added that tag, we get nice syntax highlighting :-)

Comment: Impossible to say without exact time measurement. I guess your real class has more that one method... So, just measure the time using `StopWatch`

Comment: BTW, you can execute Reflection code only once, and generate `Dictionary<string, DelegateDef>` which contains delegate for every  method name. In `ExecuteMethod` just use this dictionary - this can be a good compromise.

Comment: Yes, my class has about 20 methods.

Comment: BTW I'd be satisfied if I knew that the difference won't be huge. As I said, my target is mobile devices and I just want to be sure that this part of program won't stall the app. Also, I think I can say that in worst case scenario, this part will be executed twice per second. About the Dictionary,(I'm kind of new to programming:p) does it have optimizations to make it faster than switch-case?

Comment: Writing this kind of code is painful, not in the least because delegates are strongly type-checked, even if you late-bind them like you do.  Maybe you can use reflection to make it less painful but it isn't very clear from the question what type of arguments these methods take.  High odds that this is painful because you shouldn't be doing this at all.  It isn't clear why you think you need to do this.

Comment: I'm developing a card game, in which different cards have different effects. And card definitions are presented as a file by designer, indicating what effect/ability should the card have.

Comment: By they way, all methods in my MethodCollection class have same and specific signature without exception. The text only indicates the name of the method.